# Stop S3 recursive event using custom header parameters

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an event associated with S3 PUTS that will trigger a lambda. This lambda in turn updates the same object in S3. I want to avoid recursive S3 updates. Can I pass any custom header value as part of S3 PUT that can be used to stop the lambda from getting triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use object tagging https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-tagging.html and mark your object as 'handled'. with this you can stop the recursion.

Comment: Thank you , a bunch of other lambdas update the same object with different values and this needs to trigger the event. I am assuming this tag will be attached to the object as meta data and I need to add logic in all the other lambdas to remove or set different tag.

Comment: Lets assume you have 3 lambda functions [A,B,C]. You add a tag named 'handlers'. This tag will hold the handlers. After A will handle it the tag will look like handlers=A. Later when B will handle the file it will look like handlers=A,B . Each function will ask the logical question "did I handle this file" by looking into the handlers "array"

Comment: Thanks , some of those lambda functions are not in my control , so is there a solution that I can use which would limit it to a change in single lambda?